# Store All Post Categories In Array

Tags: categories, id

I'm trying to collect a list of all categories used on posts. However, the following code only returns the first category. How could this be adapted to collect all categories, if the post has multiples?

```
$category = get_the_category();
$the_cats[] = $category[0]->term_id;
```

Ultimately, I would like to use the `term_id` list to show/hide HTML elements on the page, depending on the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
wp_get_post_categories()
```

Check more reference from here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Comment: Awesome. I've now got a working array. Thanks for the pointer...